# Inequality on Frobenius norms of the difference of 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-norms

Can I write $$|| V D_1 D_2 V^T -Q D_1 D_2 Q^T||_F \le f(D_1,D_2)_F  || V D_2 V^T -Q D_2 Q^T||_F $$

for some $f$? I have that $V$ and $Q$ are orthonormal matrices, $D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagonal matrices. I don't think Cauchy-Schwarz covers it. I don't need this precise inequality, I just want a bound as a function of the two terms shown on the right-hand side.

Comment: Yeah I had thought about that, I was just wondering if D1 is "further away" from the identity, whether something could come up.

Answer (score 1):

No such $f$ exists. Consider the case where $D_2=I$ and $V,Q$ are orthogonal matrices. Then the RHS of your inequality is zero. Hence the LHS is necessarily zero, i.e., the inequality implies that $VD_1V^T=QD_1Q^T$ for every diagonal matrix $D_1$ and orthogonal matrices $V,Q$, which is clearly untrue.

However, if we put $X=VD_1V^T,\,Y=VD_2V^T,\,Z=QD_1Q^T$ and $W=QD_2Q^T$, we do have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\|VD_1D_2V^T-QD_1D_2Q^T\|_F\\
&=\|XY-ZW\|_F\\
&=\|XY-XW+XW-ZW\|_F\\
&\le\|XY-XW\|_F+\|XW-ZW\|_F\\
&=\|X(Y-W)\|_F+\|(X-Z)W\|_F\\
&\le\|X\|_F\|Y-W\|_F+\|X-Z\|_F\|W\|_F\\
&\le\|D_1\|_F\|VD_2V^T-QD_2Q^T\|_F+\|VD_1V^T-QD_1Q^T\|_F\|D_2\|_F.
\end{aligned}
$$